# Django groups and permissions in API level (with django-rest-framework)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-permissions

Consider the following scenario;
I have a bunch of **Users** and **API classes**. I need to restrict access to each API by checking the requested user's group permissions and allow the user to do group permitted stuff.
Suppose I have a user `user_xx`, he belongs to group `group_xx` and has permissions `activity | activity | Can add activity`. When `user_xx` tries to access `MyActivityAPI` through `HTTP-DELETE` method the view class should restrict the access.
Can do I achieve this feature? If possible, How?
**What I'd tried**
Created some groups & assigned permissions to them and added users to their corresponding groups. I tried to access one of the restricted api, but it allows me to access (expected behaviour : restrict the user from the api).
**UPDATE :**
here is my simple `views.py`

```
class MyApi(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the approaches mentioned in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/ ?

Comment: I already tried this.

Comment: Can you post the code of your views/viewsets so far?

Comment: I updated the question, though I have a simple view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the docs, in order for the Django model permissions to be applied to the viewset you have to use [`DjangoModelPermissions`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions):

```
class MyApi(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (DjangoModelPermissions,)
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

In your previous code all actions were allowed to any authenticated user because you were using `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)`.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I think I missed that part of the documentation.